# Syntax error cannot figure out why

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Hi I keep getting a syntax error but I cant figure out why. My code is

```
data = numpy.loadtxt((etf + '.csv',dtype = ([("date", "S8"), ("value", "f8")]), delimiter= ',' , usecols=(0,-1)))
x = numpy.arange(len(data))
pl1.bar(x,data["value"], width = 0.8)
p1.xticks(x+.4, data["date"])
p1.show()
```

and the syntax error is

```
  data = numpy.loadtxt((etf + '.csv',dtype = ([("date", "S8"), ("value", "f8")]), delimiter= ',' , usecols=(0,-1)))
                                           ^
```

Thanks

Comment: I see a parenthesis mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = numpy.loadtxt((etf + '.csv',
```

Once you get to here, Python thinks you're building a tuple to send as one argument to `loadtxt`, rather than sending multiple arguments. So,

```
   dtype = ([("date", "S8"), ("value", "f8")])
```

errors because the `=` isn't valid in a tuple. You probably meant to do this:

```
data = numpy.loadtxt((etf + '.csv'), ... )
```

But the extra brackets around `etf + '.csv'` aren't needed here - the string concatenation takes precedence anyway, so you can just remove the second `(` and everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra paren in front of etf

```
data = numpy.loadtxt(etf + '.csv',dtype = ([("date", "S8"), ("value", "f8")]), delimiter= ',' , usecols=(0,-1))
```